# Casting BitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer to long

Tags: c#, .net, image

I’m having some troubles understanding what exactly is happening with Scan0.ToPointer when I cast it to a different type. I have the following code to write data to a 48bpp image:

```
BitmapData combinedBitmapData = m_CombinedBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 512, 512), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
int incr = 48 / 16;

long dataCombined = (long)combinedBitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();
long nextBase = dataCombined + combinedBitmapData.Stride;

for (int y = 0; y < combinedBitmapData.Height; ++y)
{
    ushort* dataCombinedPtr = (ushort*)dataCombined;

    for (int x = 0; x < combinedBitmapData.Width; ++x)
    {
        dataCombinedPtr[2] = 0;
        dataCombinedPtr[1] = 65535;
        dataCombinedPtr[0] = 0;

        dataCombinedPtr += incr;
    }

    dataCombined = nextBase;
    nextBase += combinedBitmapData.Stride;
}
```

The problem area is:

```
long bData1Scan0Ptr = (long)combinedBitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();
```

I don’t understand why I have to cast it to a long first and then in the first for-loop cast it to a ushort*. I can also cast it to a byte* first and it will also work. 
However, it will crash when I cast it to a ushort* directly and remove the second (now useless cast) in the first for-loop.

To summarize, why do I need to cast it to long/byte* before casting it to ushort*?

Comment: This looks like a train-wreck.  Do you realize that there is not a single image format encoder that knows how to handle a 48bpp pixel format?  You can't paint it either.  It was added to GDI+ with the assumption that hardware would evolve to support it.  That didn't happen.

Comment: @Hans: I think you mean that "not a single encoder *shipped as part of .NET* knows how to handle 48bpp".  I believe there are quite a few third-party libraries that do, and conform to the .NET image encoder interface.  In any case, this question would be equally interesting for 16bpp greyscale data (yeah I know, not supported by the BCL encoders either) or to access 32bpp ARGB data pixel-at-a-time (that does work with image formats supported by BCL)

Comment: @Hans Passant I’m currently loading in the 48bpp tiff image with WPF using TiffBitmapDecoder, I then use [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory")] public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, long Length); to copy the WriteableBitmap to a normal GDI+ Bitmap. I never display this image, but I do save it in the end as a png, and it saves it as a 48bpp image when I check the properties. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @HansPassant I think I understand now, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28VS.80%29.aspx, so even if I copy it in a 48bpp GDI+ bitmap the colors still get converted to 8bpp... Do I need a third-party library, or can I just use the writeableBitmap WPF class? Will this keep all the 16bit/channel information? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting it directly to `ushort*` is not a problem.

Changing the arithmetic `dataCombined + combinedBitmapData.Stride` from `long` to `ushort*` is a problem.  **In pointer arithmetic, you don't add the number of bytes, you add the number of elements**, and the compiler multiplies by the element size to get the number of bytes.  But **`Stride` is already measured in bytes**.  This is also why casting to `byte*` worked -- because then elements and bytes are the same, the element size is 1, and the multiplication does nothing.

If you really want to get rid of the extra casts, this will probably work (it requires the stride to be a multiple of 16 bits, for Win32 bitmaps the stride is always a multiple of 32-bits):

```
BitmapData combinedBitmapData = m_CombinedBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 512, 512), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
int incr = 48 / 16;

ushort* dataCombinedPtr = (ushort*)combinedBitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();
for (int y = 0; y < combinedBitmapData.Height; ++y)
{
    ushort* nextScan = dataCombinedPtr + combinedBitmapData.Stride / 2; // convert from bytes to elements
    for (int x = 0; x < combinedBitmapData.Width; ++x)
    {
        dataCombinedPtr[2] = 0;
        dataCombinedPtr[1] = 65535;
        dataCombinedPtr[0] = 0;

        dataCombinedPtr += incr;
    }

    dataCombinedPtr = nextScan;
}
```

The key is to **express all offsets in elements instead of bytes, when doing pointer arithmetic**.  That's what `incr = 48 / 16;` was doing in the original code (actually, converting from *bits* to elements)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I will definitely read up on pointer arithmetic.